# Setting attribute on element gives error "Cannot set property '...' of undefined' with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element

I'm trying to set up a custom element using polymer that consists of a draggable box with an icon in it.  I'd like to be able to define the icon by specifying an `icon` attribute on the element, so that I can declarative create elements rather than defining a `setIcon` method on the element, which would only be accessible through javascript.

I've tried to set my element up to handle the attribute by including a `properties` attribute on the element prototype I'm feeding into polymer, giving me element code that looks something like this:

```
var elementProto = {
    is : "my-element",
    behaviors : [someOtherProto],
    properties : {
        icon : {
            "type" : "String",
            "observer" : "_iconObserver",
        }
    },
    _iconObserver : function(){ /* Functionality for adding icon */}
};

elementProto.otherMethods = various functions;

Polymer(elementProto);
```

In another file, I'm then trying to set my icon attribute using `setAttribute` in another javascript function, (after importing my new element via its associated html file) like so:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("my-element");
newElement.setAttribute("icon", "some/icon/path.png");
```

Ideally, this would fire my observer function with the new path as an argument and I would set the URL for the image in my new element to whatever that path was. Instead, Chrome gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'icon' of undefined
```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Notes on debugging:

I've dug into the polymer code and found that the error originates from this line:

```
var model = this._clientsReadied ? this : this._config;
```

Both `this._clientsReadied` and `this._config` are undefined, which is causing this error in the `._setAttributeToProperty(model, name);` method, where `name` is set as an attribute on `model`. I don't know enough about polymer to know why those attributes would be undefined, though.

Comment: Have you tried using polymer's `set` method like `elementRef.set('property', 'value')`?

Comment: @Alan I tried `element.setAttribute`, `element.set`, `Polymer.dom(element).set` (which is undefined), and `Polymer.dom(element).setAttribute`.

Comment: You know, I tried making a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/375chjk2/) with your code and it works just fine... Maybe you have some missing imports?

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?

You are getting this error because at the time you invoke `createElement()`, your Custom Element is not registered yet. Probably because the 2 files are parsed in the wrong order.

To fix this issue, you can try to change the order of the imported files, or you can wait for the `HTMLImportsLoaded`, or `WebComponentsReady` event.

```
document.addEventListener("HTMLImportsLoaded", function () 
{
    var newElement = document.createElement("my-element");
    newElement.setAttribute("icon", "some/icon/path.png");
});
```